# StackOverflowError ao usar um método

Tags: java, android

Seguinte, estou no desenvolvimento de um aplicativo. Nele existem dois métodos de cálculo, onde na entrada de dados o usuário escolhe o método e insere os dados. Um desses métodos está funcionando perfeitamente. Já o outro causa o problema da figura a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se minha pergunta está vaga... peço até desculpas por isso.

Ressalto que a diferença entre um cálculo e outro é que o que está dando erro tem a seleção e o envio de dados em forma de spinner para a outra Activity. Será que pode ser isso?

```
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 29379(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 83MB/83MB, paused 96.984ms total 175.964ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 34691(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 14(41MB) LOS objects, 14% free, 47MB/55MB, paused 732us total 146.057ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 48902(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(4MB) LOS objects, 12% free, 55MB/63MB, paused 793us total 125.335ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 41873(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(10MB) LOS objects, 12% free, 54MB/62MB, paused 762us total 130.004ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 41159(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(9MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 59MB/67MB, paused 793us total 124.847ms
D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
D/Error: ERR: file=Resultado.java
D/Error: ERR: class=uerj.dcad.Resultado
D/Error: ERR: method=massa_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin line=400
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin(Resultado.java:400)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_superplastificante_aitcin(Resultado.java:406)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.volume_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin(Resultado.java:418)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.volume_areia_atcin(Resultado.java:492)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:369)
             at uerj.dcad.Resultado.massa_areia_aitcin(Resultado.java:498)
            at uerj.dcad.Resultado
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 36(2816B) AllocSpace objects, 1(13MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 69MB/77MB, paused 946us total 156.280ms
D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 12750340
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4386)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:95)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25625 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
```

**Funções de Calculo**

```html
public double agua_material_cimenticio_aitcin(){ // RESULTADO

        return resultado = -log(resistencia_concreto/523.17)/6.255;

    }

    private double massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin(){

        return resultado = 8.9286 * ponto_saturacao * ponto_saturacao + 29.643 * ponto_saturacao + 101.21;

    }

    public double massa_agua_final_aitcin(){ // RESULTADO

        // correcao_agua_superplastificante_aitcin() = massa_superplastificante_agua_aitcin()

        return resultado = massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin()-massa_superplastificante_agua_aitcin()+correcao_agua_areia_aitcin()+correcao_agua_brita_aitcin();

    }

    public double correcao_agua_brita_aitcin(){

        return resultado = (-1)*massa_brita_aitcin()*(teor_agua_brita-absorcao_agua_brita)/100;

    }

    public double correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(){

        return resultado = (-1)*massa_areia_aitcin()*(teor_agua_areia-absorcao_agua_areia)/100;

    }

    public double massa_aditivo_mineral1_aitcin(){ // RESULTADO

        return resultado = teor_aditivo_mineral1*massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin()/(100*agua_material_cimenticio_aitcin());

    }

    public double massa_aditivo_mineral2_aitcin(){ // RESULTADO

        return resultado = teor_aditivo_mineral2*massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin()/(100*agua_material_cimenticio_aitcin());

    }

    public double massa_superplastificante_aitcin(){ //RESULTADO

        double massa_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin = ponto_saturacao*massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin()/agua_material_cimenticio_aitcin();

        return resultado = 100*massa_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin/teor_solidos;

    }

    public double massa_superplastificante_agua_aitcin(){

        double massa_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin = ponto_saturacao*massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin()/agua_material_cimenticio_aitcin();

        return resultado = massa_superplastificante_aitcin()-massa_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin;

    }

    public double massa_cimento_aitcin(){ // RESULTADO

        return resultado = (massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin()/agua_material_cimenticio_aitcin())-massa_aditivo_mineral1_aitcin()-massa_aditivo_mineral2_aitcin();

    }

    public double massa_brita_aitcin(){

        if (formato_agregado.equals("Alongado")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 950;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Alongado à Lamelar")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 975;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Lamelar")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 1000;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Lamelar à Médio")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 1025;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Médio")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 1050;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Médio à Cúbico")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 1075;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Cúbico")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 1100;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Cúbico à Arredondado")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 1125;

        }else if (formato_agregado.equals("Arredondado")){

            resultado_formato_agregado = 1150;

        }

        return resultado = resultado_formato_agregado - correcao_agua_brita_aitcin();

    }

    public double volume_areia_atcin(){

        double volume_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin = (massa_superplastificante_aitcin()/massa_especifica_aditivo_quimico)-massa_superplastificante_agua_aitcin();
        double volume_cimento_aitcin = massa_cimento_aitcin()/massa_especifica_cimento;
        double volume_aditivo_mineral1_aitcin = massa_aditivo_mineral1_aitcin()/massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral1;
        double volume_aditivo_mineral2_aitcin = massa_aditivo_mineral2_aitcin()/massa_especifica_aditivo_mineral2;
        double volume_brita_aitcin = (massa_brita_aitcin()+correcao_agua_brita_aitcin())/massa_especifica_sss_brita;

        return resultado = 1000-massa_agua_ponto_saturacao_superplastificante_aitcin() - volume_superplastificante_solidos_aitcin - volume_cimento_aitcin - volume_aditivo_mineral1_aitcin - volume_aditivo_mineral2_aitcin - volume_brita_aitcin-10*ar_incorporado;

    }

    public double massa_areia_aitcin(){ // RESULTADO

        return resultado = (volume_areia_atcin()-correcao_agua_areia_aitcin())*massa_especifica_sss_areia;

    }
```

Comment: Coloca a parte do código que possa estar a originar o erro.

Comment: ramaral, coloquei! será que pode ter algo relacionado à passagem de parâmetros da spinner?!

Comment: Voce ta tendo um erro de stackoverflow (e nao eh piadinha com o nome do site kkk) ou seja, de forma muito simples, a quantidade de recursos alocada nao foi suficiente pro que vc deseja fazer. Pelo que eu vi nas suas funcoes vc esta chamando umas as outras, talvez voce poderia repensar o fluxo pra ver se isso nao acaba gerando uma recursao infinita que acaba usando todos os recursos ate dar o erro de stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso o erro é devido a um método chamar outro que, por sua vez, chama o primeiro.
Isto provoca um *loop* infinito, acabando por resultar em um erro de *StackOverflowError*.

Observe os seguintes dois métodos:

```
public double correcao_agua_areia_aitcin(){

    return resultado = (-1)*massa_areia_aitcin()*(teor_agua_areia-absorcao_agua_areia)/100;

}

public double massa_areia_aitcin(){ // RESULTADO

    return resultado = (volume_areia_atcin()-correcao_agua_areia_aitcin())*massa_especifica_sss_areia;

}
```

`correcao_agua_areia_aitcin()` chama `massa_areia_aitcin()`que por sua vez chama `correcao_agua_areia_aitcin()`.